# Pyplot and Tkinter - Unwanted Extra Window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

My code below creates an unwanted duplicate window when I try to add a window title using `plt.figure().canvas.manager.set_window_title("Custom Title")`.

I've done some research and discovered that I am probably not supposed to be mixing `pyplot` and `tkinter` this way as they get confused. However I couldn't really make sense of the proposed solutions, some of which used something called `FigureCanvasTkAgg` which I don't know about. I want my plot to be freestanding, just as it is when I remove `plt.figure().canvas.manager.set_window_title("Custom Title")`.

How can I refactor my code please to not violate any principles which my current code does and to remove the unwanted window?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
import networkx as nx


NUM_ROWS = 5
BOLD_FONT = ("calbri", 12, "bold")
NORMAL_FONT = ("calbri", 12, "normal")


def create_widgets():
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
        key = chr(i + 65)
        this_row = widgets[key] = {}
        this_row["label"] = tk.Label(root, text=key, font=BOLD_FONT)
        this_row["label"].grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
        this_row["factor_field"] = tk.Entry(root, width=60, font=NORMAL_FONT)
        this_row["factor_field"].grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        this_row["target_node_field"] = tk.Entry(
            root, width=5, font=NORMAL_FONT)
        this_row["target_node_field"].grid(row=i, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        
    submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit,
                              font=BOLD_FONT).grid(row=NUM_ROWS + 1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)


def submit():
    plt.close()
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    edges = []
    for key, row in widgets.items():
        factor_field_contents = row["factor_field"].get()
        target_node_field_contents = row["target_node_field"].get().upper()
        if factor_field_contents != "" and target_node_field_contents != "":
            edges.append((key, target_node_field_contents))
            data[key] = {"factor": factor_field_contents,
                         "target_node": target_node_field_contents}
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    # pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=1.0, iterations=50)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=500, node_color="green")
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_color="white")
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(
        G, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1', width=2, arrows=True)
    plt.figure().canvas.manager.set_window_title("Custom Title")
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {}
    widgets = {}
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("My App")
    create_widgets()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you found a solution in `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, but you don't understand it. You have to gain that understanding because it is literally the only way (according to my research). My example should get you started in that understanding. To be honest, I don't know anything, at all, about `matplotlib`. I just read the docs and fulfilled the requirements. It seems to work perfectly at creating a single window.

```
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #remove this, you can't use it anymore
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as tk
import networkx as nx


NUM_ROWS = 5
BOLD_FONT = ("calbri", 12, "bold")
NORMAL_FONT = ("calbri", 12, "normal")


def create_widgets():
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
        key = chr(i + 65)
        this_row = widgets[key] = {}
        this_row["label"] = tk.Label(root, text=key, font=BOLD_FONT)
        this_row["label"].grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
        this_row["factor_field"] = tk.Entry(root, width=60, font=NORMAL_FONT)
        this_row["factor_field"].grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        this_row["target_node_field"] = tk.Entry(
            root, width=5, font=NORMAL_FONT)
        this_row["target_node_field"].grid(row=i, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        
    submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit,
                              font=BOLD_FONT).grid(row=NUM_ROWS + 1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

#this is your single window
#I'm sure some of this could be made just once and reused
#I'm also sure this could be made more dynamic
#At least you have the multi-window part solved
def plotter():
    global plotwin
    plotwin = tk.Toplevel(root)
    
    fig     = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    fig.add_subplot(111)
    
    canvas  = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, plotwin)
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    
    NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, plotwin, pack_toolbar=True).update()

def submit():
    try:
        #if plotter() hasn't been called yet this will throw a NameError
        #we simply catch and ignore it
        plotwin.destroy()
    except NameError as e:
        pass
        
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    edges = []
    for key, row in widgets.items():
        factor_field_contents = row["factor_field"].get()
        target_node_field_contents = row["target_node_field"].get().upper()
        if factor_field_contents != "" and target_node_field_contents != "":
            edges.append((key, target_node_field_contents))
            data[key] = {"factor": factor_field_contents,
                         "target_node": target_node_field_contents}
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    # pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=1.0, iterations=50)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=500, node_color="green")
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_color="white")
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1', width=2, arrows=True)

    #instantiate window
    plotter()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {}
    widgets = {}
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("My App")
    create_widgets()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You couldve read the docs like the for my Q too :( lol xp

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ Not exactly. I can't get `selenium` to properly work with py 3.8, which means I can't test `selenium` derived code. For this question I already had everything except `networkx` ~ which installed without a hitch.

Comment: Actually the selenium part is fine, i just use it for the authentication and access token, i can directly give those to you ;)

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ maybe tomorrow. I'm working on `ctk`. Believe it or not, I have my own projects. `ctk` is up to 29 custom widgets. Some of your questions are actually responsible for a couple of them. Actually, many questions from numerous inquirers are responsible for probably half of them. I've even taken this `matplotlib` window and classed it out. I need to study a bit more to understand what kind of interface to build for it to make it reusable.

Comment: Its fine, take your time, just let me know when your free for it :D and all the best!

Comment: i dont check it quite often, but when i see the message, ill let you know or if you instagram its fine too

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ I sent you a reference to my real email. I don't instagram, facebook, twitter or anything else. Too much of a waste of time. All my free time is spent becoming a better programmer.

Comment: Yep, replied too. So this is how you stay productive with no social media ;)

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ honestly, I spend so much time writing and thinking abut code that I find it complicated to communicate with people. That's why my answers are generally found in code comments. Explaining myself in paragraphs is usually an exercise in grasping for the most simple way to say something and my brain throwing a bunch of errors. Even this took way too long to write. In code comments all I have to be is correct.

Comment: lol, thats sad and good at the same time, one of the moderator is prolly gonna move this conversation to chat

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ ::shrugs:: If I had the power to trigger a chat they wouldn't have to spend time moving it to one for me. By the time the "move this to chat" message has appeared, so much has been said that it's like "What's the point?". They should have given me that option like 10 comments ago ~ or simply let me trigger it on demand.

Comment: Just typical SO